# Change the value of an object property name inside an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object

I have the following code:

```
const truth = [{
  question: "Question 1",
  hasAppeard: false
}, {
  question: "Question 1",
  hasAppeard: false
}]
```

and I am trying to change the value of `hasAppeard` to `true`, when the question has appeared so I can filter the questions and show `onClick` only the ones that has not appeared again.

I know how to change the value from an object like:

```
const something = {
  a: false,
  b: false
}
something.b = true
```

but in this situation I am stuck and can't find how to access and change it as per the question that has appeared.

The full code is as follow:

Questions.js

```
const truth = [
  {question: "Question 1", hasAppeard: false},
  {question: "Question 2", hasAppeard: false},
  {question: "Question 3", hasAppeard: false},
  {question: "Question 4", hasAppeard: false}
]

const dare = [
  {question: "Question 5", hasAppeard: false},
  {question: "Question 6", hasAppeard: false},
  {question: "Question 7", hasAppeard: false},
  {question: "Question 8", hasAppeard: false}
]

export {truth, dare};
```

App.js

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
  super();
  this.state = {
    currQuest: null,
  }
}

handleRandomTruth = () => {
  this.setState({
  currQuest: truth[Math.floor(Math.random() * truth.length)]
 })
}

handleRandomDare = () => {
  this.setState({
  currQuest: dare[Math.floor(Math.random() * dare.length)]
 })
}

render() {
 return (
  <div className="App">
     <div className="timer">
       <CountdownTimer />
     </div>

     <div className="current-player">
       <h3>current player</h3>
     </div>

     <div className="next-player">
       <h3>next player</h3>
     </div>

     <div className="questions">
        {this.state.currQuest ? <div>{this.state.currQuest.question} 
      </div> : ''}
     </div>

   <button className="btn-truth" onClick= 
     {this.handleRandomTruth}>Truth</button>
   <button className="btn-dare" onClick= 
     {this.handleRandomDare}>Dare</button>
   <button className="btn-home" >Home</button>
  </div>
  );
 }
}

export default App;
```

I am new in programming and I'm trying to make a truth or dare game to learn react. I have read about arrays and objects but I am confused and I can not find what I am looking for.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
handleRandomTruth = () => {
  let validTruths = truth.filter(t => !t.hasAppeard);
  let randomNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * validTruths.length);
  this.setState({
    currQuest: validTruths[randomNum]
  })
  truth[randomNum].hasAppeard = true
}
```

The same logic appeals to `dare` as well.

Comment: Thank you! At the end of the array it sticks with the last question. I will try to check if all questions are "hasAppeard: true" to return a custom message.

Answer (score 1):

You could filter out all dares or truths that haven't appeared yet, pick one of those randomly, and then change the `hasAppeard` field for that object in the original array.

**Example**

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    currQuest: null,
    truth: [
      { question: "Question 1", hasAppeard: false },
      { question: "Question 2", hasAppeard: false },
      { question: "Question 3", hasAppeard: false },
      { question: "Question 4", hasAppeard: false }
    ],
    dare: [
      { question: "Question 5", hasAppeard: false },
      { question: "Question 6", hasAppeard: false },
      { question: "Question 7", hasAppeard: false },
      { question: "Question 8", hasAppeard: false }
    ]
  };

  handleRandomTruth = () => {
    this.setState(prevState => {
      const truth = [...prevState.truth];
      const unappearedTruths = truth.filter(t => !t.hasAppeard);
      const randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * unappearedTruths.length);
      const truthIndex = truth.indexOf(unappearedTruths[randomIndex]);

      truth[truthIndex] = { ...truth[truthIndex], hasAppeard: true };

      return { truth, currQuest: unappearedTruths[randomIndex] };
    });
  };

  handleRandomDare = () => {
    this.setState(prevState => {
      const dare = [...prevState.dare];
      const unappearedDares = dare.filter(d => !d.hasAppeard);
      const randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * unappearedDares.length);
      const dareIndex = dare.indexOf(unappearedDares[randomIndex]);

      dare[dareIndex] = { ...dare[dareIndex], hasAppeard: true };

      return { dare, currQuest: unappearedDares[randomIndex] };
    });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <div className="current-player">
          <h3>current player</h3>
        </div>

        <div className="next-player">
          <h3>next player</h3>
        </div>

        <div className="questions">
          {this.state.currQuest ? (
            <div>{this.state.currQuest.question}</div>
          ) : (
            ""
          )}
        </div>

        <button className="btn-truth" onClick={this.handleRandomTruth}>
          Truth
        </button>
        <button className="btn-dare" onClick={this.handleRandomDare}>
          Dare
        </button>
        <button className="btn-home">Home</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much! In this implementation is not possible to keep the questions in a separate component because later I will have more questions?

Answer (score 0):

You need to first access the object using number based access and then change that objects property.

An example to change the hasAppeard of 3rd object of truth array is as follow:

```js
const truth = [
  {question: "Question 1", hasAppeard: false},
  {question: "Question 2", hasAppeard: false},
  {question: "Question 3", hasAppeard: false},
  {question: "Question 4", hasAppeard: false}
];

truth[2].hasAppeard = true; // array index starts at 0

console.log(truth);
```

Answer (score 0):

How about that? :

```
handleRandomTruth = () => {
   let q = truth[Math.floor(Math.random() * truth.length)]
   const retries = 10
   while (q.hasAppeard === true && retries-- >= 0)
       q = truth[Math.floor(Math.random() * truth.length)]
   q.hasAppeard = true
   this.setState({
       currQuest: q
   })
}
```